# Show multiple location on Google Maps on Android Wear

Tags: android, google-maps, wear-os

I have searched a lot to find the way of **showing multiple locations on google map in android wear**.

But didn't find any appropriate link regarding that.

I know I can show map on android wear but i display only current location of user.

I have gone through the below links.

1) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/wear?hl=en

2) http://liliputing.com/2015/05/google-maps-now-runs-on-android-wear-smartwatches.html

But what I want is mark multiple locations on map. Please guide me regarding this and suggest some way to make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i did not work yet with the Google Maps API but i used it in some examples to test it on wear, i think you can use the `addMarker` method of `GoogleMap` class,

it is the same approach as on handheld devices.

if the map is showing on the wear you can test the method by adding multiples markers.